# grouping first few elements together

Tags: java, arraylist

My following code does the randomization of an array, however, I am wondering if I want to group first two or three elements together always, how should I proceed?

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i=1;i<=11;i++)
{
    numbers.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(numbers);


for (Integer nums : numbers)
    System.out.println(nums);
```

Example Output: 5, 7, 4, 11, 2, 3, 1, 9, 6, 8, 10
(Note that the sequence '1,2,3' is randomized within the main array.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
final int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
final int iterations = 10;
final int groupOf = 3;

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i += groupOf) {
    int groupOfRemainder = array.length - i < groupOf ? array.length - i : groupOf;
    for (int j = 0; j < iterations; j++) {
        int rnd1 = Math.random() * groupOfRemainder;
        int rnd2 = Math.random() * groupOfRemainder;

        Object temp = array[i + rnd1];
        array[i + rnd1] = array[i + rnd2];
        array[i + rnd2] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your line `array[i + rnd2] ;` is throwing an error `not a statement`

Comment: Fixed. Missed the "= temp;".

Comment: Thanks, simply printing `System.out.println(array);` outside for loop is printing `[I@7852e922`  as I believe I am printing the value of an object

Comment: @John To print an array you have to write `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void shuffleKeepingFirstRTogether(List<Integer> list, int r) {
    int size = list.size();
    Collections.shuffle(list.subList(0, r));
    Collections.shuffle(list.subList(r, size));
    Collections.rotate(list, new Random().nextInt(size - r));
}
```

Comment: I updated my post with more detail. I want the first three elements to be in random order as well but always together.

Comment: Hi, what if i have multiple such groups of r?